# Get Name/Sid from Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPTrustee using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, group-policy

I am trying to get the permissions applied on Group Policy Object using **Get-GPPermission** cmdlet in C#.(without using Microsoft.GroupPolicy namespace) I am able to get values of permission type and inherited properties, but could not fetch Name or Sid of Trustee.

Below is the code snippet:

```cs
    Type gpTrusteeType = obj.Members["Trustee"].Value.GetType();
    object gpTrustee = Activator.CreateInstance(gpTrusteeType);   
    gpTrustee = obj.Members["Trustee"].Value;
    PropertyInfo name = gpTrusteeType.GetProperty("Name");
    String trusteeName = name.GetValue(gpTrustee, null).ToSring();
```

Error Message: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Tried using ConstructorInfo, but it didn't help

Comment: Where is the exception occurring?  The error is indicating that you are calling a constructor which means "new" is in the c# instruction.  No "new" is shown in code above.  The error simply means you need to add a missing parameter to the call like : new myClass(parameter) where parameter is the missing parameter.

Comment: I am trying to get the properties of Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GpTrustee type which is returned as the result(PSObject) by running Get-GPPermission. I also tried creating instance of GpTrustee type using Activator.CreateInstance(gpTrusteeType, BindingFlags.NonPublic |  BindingFlags.Instance,  null, new Object[] {Type.Missing}, null) but getting "Constructor on type 'System.String' not found." error message

Comment: You curly bracket is in the wrong place.  Should be : new Object[] {Type.Missing, null})

Comment: Tried it, Still getting same error message